# Update an array element in TypeScript using map

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm a bit confused with the `.map` method on my Typescript array.

I have something like a Tree of my custom type. Where each node could have sub-nodes.
I try to update a sub-node with my `nodemap_update` function which is using the `.map` method of array.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to replace the object with a *new* one. Does some one see the bug in the small demo script [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBFQAOUGkHy8xaghQBNQjhoX3mDGYKARVxOzNBamYmGgFEF9U4Iwk8DI8WE0gY3CCsEYgmEAFk8FTuCgAN6KEqcBjIWnEVCUcWgAC8oAARNaANx6kxqaJOTi09WayAAbQAupbQL6HQBfYLuVn6VAAfW4dQY7o18C1-t1+sNNJtOHgBFKz0gemg1t4jo0mO4rtpXsdJW1-TTtOtAGFndwKoWnaXywG-UGiyVq7WjTam6WAEJtksulEV7u9vs1g2DxvNhvj5ud32gHuOn2KEOKMNoCOR9gEGMKeOe5OOhfppejtvFtdTgNV0DzutD5sjgIARlXHefDctz7N8B1vYdom-AAmf9JzdLtN1nfsb3rCDuG-ABmWCy0Amdt13YIEE4QR4HcAJoHgZgAAprRwCNQAAEVjfgMnrUAAGpQAAKWIAB5CkAkEU1hgRPAqIUITo1jABKaTFCIkiyIo6jaPo+5TzqSAWPg60OO4viBKEs1tGSMSJKjE8z0gWTCMaIT+kTSBEAYAhjw0hR-SogYtQvRz+E4SAJEjbz0w9RzpMtAA+N9HW5LzHICG9LQtK0AqCkLErTCKUz7BTSMgcjKKogByZIOB4UBir0jKb2kh0QJC-00uCxz6r7JxUHxLxmpCtqg3BaAGREZJ4q1AIJxwrwAEIUtALgtWSDJIG4bLXwyibXQCZyCCo0AqImiKLWinKQJKCamsc7a3Ks-bm38wKWq1OrXxAibMuQf03qSzjrXY+0Xty5tXxDEC5JAjquocrU+sdCGyG61qCMUEKrsszTxKPM8GH4czrs0uT5Ls-LCpUuj7KY5l+A4VA2M4nj+ME4TxVEjHJKxmzyTATM3A8eHQEQKVnGBdhWTuRhxXYDktJMYVYESBhgT0EQvGtABRVZDQWfRdKlG1wAcVBiuEClAutIIVF4r4yHeBl+E5I5mTIBRXGkPBQCcAWdGGLB9BQBBEGhYRLjZSUyGiEQDA4bEFiYVhyoVR0gA) (or bellow)? I'm confused why the map method is not updating the *ChildB* node but append the character '+' to the others...

The output which I get is:

```
"Test Data, out: 
{"name":"Top-Level","children":
 [{"name":"ChildA+","children":[]},
  {"name":"ChildB","children":[]},
  {"name":"ChildC+","children":[]}
 ]}"
```

and I expect this:

```
"Test Data, out: 
{"name":"Top-Level","children":
 [{"name":"ChildA+","children":[]},
  {"name":"ChildB",children: [
    { name: "ChildB.1", children: [] },
    { name: "ChildB.2", children: [] },
    { name: "ChildB.3", children: [] },
  ]},
  {"name":"ChildC+","children":[]}
 ]}"



class MyNode {
  name: String = "";
  children: MyNode[] = [];
}

let test_data: MyNode = {
  name: "Top-Level",
  children: [
    { name: "ChildA", children: [] },
    { name: "ChildB", children: [] },
    { name: "ChildC", children: [] },
  ]
}

let test_update: MyNode = {
  name: "ChildB", 
  children: [
    { name: "ChildB.1", children: [] },
    { name: "ChildB.2", children: [] },
    { name: "ChildB.3", children: [] },
  ]
}

console.log("Test Data: " + JSON.stringify(test_data))
console.log("Test Update: " + JSON.stringify(test_update))

const nodemap_update = (node: MyNode, new_node: MyNode) => {
    console.log('search for ' + new_node.name + ' in ' + node.name);
  if (node.name === new_node.name) {
    console.log('found ' + node.name);
    node = new_node;
    return new_node;
  } else if(node.children !== undefined) {
    node.children.map( (child) => {
        child = nodemap_update(child, new_node);
        child.name = child.name + "+";
        child
    }
    )
    return node;
  }
  return node;
}

let new_data = nodemap_update(test_data, test_update)

console.log("New Data: " + JSON.stringify(new_data))
console.log("Test Data: " + JSON.stringify(test_data))
console.log("Test Update: " + JSON.stringify(test_update))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found an issue.

In the first `if` statement you were *reassigning* the `node` variable from your function arguments (which is, by the way, the practice you should avoid in Javascript), instead of *modifying* properties of the `node` itself.

The way to modify it is to edit its properties values using the `<variable_name>.<property_name> = value` syntax, that you used in the second `if` statement (this is the reason why it was actually adding `"+"` after the name).

If I understood everything correctly, the proper way of dealing with your task is to do something like this:

```
function nodemap_update(node: MyNode, new_node: MyNode): MyNode {
   if (node.name === new_node.name) {
       // Actually modifying the value of node variable, mutating the test_data

       node.children = new_node.children;
   } else {
       // If it's not a required node, adds plus to its name and recursively runs nodemap_update() on its children

       node.name += '+';

       node.children.forEach((child) => nodemap_update(child, new_node));
   }

   return node;
}
```

As a last piece of an advice, this is considered better to use `[].forEach()` instead of `[].map()` in cases when you don't require the resulting array.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Wow, nice thanks for the correct Hint. One last question about the _modifying_ of properties. I understand somehow why it should be avoided. Is it ok to use something like this: `Object.assign(node, new_node)` ? I'm asking, because in my _real_ use case the class has several properties and I try to avoid to copy them all manually.

Comment: Surely, this method is more applicable in your case, despite it also modifies the function arguments.

Regarding the avoiding of modifying the values of the arguments, it's considered as an anti-pattern _when you have a lot of functions that mutates your data_. With the amount of these functions growing, it's simply becoming harder to track which of them are actually edited your data, which often produces bugs.

To keep your code base healthy and easier to track, I would suggest you to move your function into methods of `MyNode`